# line count on all the PHP scripts within my webroot with wc

Tags: directory, utilities, recursive

How can I do a line count on all the PHP scripts within my webroot?

I am trying something like this below to no avail:

```
wc -l *.php
```

Comment: Do you search the line count in summary or for each php file separately?

Comment: How is `wc -l *.php` not working? Do you need it recursive?

Comment: @Kevin Yes, it needed to be a recursive count.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use either a shell whose wildcard expansion includes subdirectories, or to stack another tool for directory transversal, such as `find`:

`find -name "*.php" | xargs wc -l`

If, OTOH, your goal is to sum it all, join the code first:

`find -name "*.php" | xargs cat | wc -l`

Comment: Hmm...both options give an error of "find: paths must precede expression"

Comment: my bad, fixed to avoid wildcard expansion when there are *.php files in the current directory.

Comment: Thanks - the second option is exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: With caution if some filename contains spaces.

Comment: Useless use of xargs. `find -name "*.php" -exec cat {} + | wc -l`

Comment: Not white space safe, use `-print0`/`-0` or `-exec`

Answer (score 2):

With bash (only since version 4.0) you can do this:

```
shopt -s globstar
wc -l **/*.php
```

In zsh, you can always do `wc -l **/*.php`.

Comment: I'm using Bash 3.2.25 and get the following error: "-bash: shopt: globstar: invalid shell option name"

Answer (score 1):

You need to enable bashs `globstar` option, so ** matches all files and subdirectories:

```
shopt -s globstar
wc -l **/*.php
```

There are also tools like [cloc](http://cloc.sourceforge.net/) made for generating such statistics.

Comment: Note: only bash 4+